# Consume SOAP web service with security in Mule flow

Tags: java, spring, soap, mule, cxf

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service that requires security using CXF in Mule. I have got it working, but I need to put the password in a config file. I can't find how to pass the password from the config to the flow/callback class. My flow looks like this:

```
<cxf:jaxws-client 
    clientClass="za.co.iam.service.identitymanager.intf._1.IdentityManager_Service"
    port="IdentityManager"
    wsdlLocation="classpath:/wsdl/IdentityManager.wsdl"
    operation="CheckUserId" doc:name="CXF">
    <cxf:ws-security>
        <cxf:ws-config>
            <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp"/>
            <cxf:property key="user" value="${security.username}"/>
            <cxf:property key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/> 
            <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" value="za.co.iam.IamPasswordCallback"/>
        </cxf:ws-config>
    </cxf:ws-security>
</cxf:jaxws-client>
<outbound-endpoint address="${iam.webservice}" doc:name="Generic"/>
```

The `IamPasswordCallback` class:

```
public class IamPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {
  public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException
  {
     WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
     pc.setPassword("********");
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I need to put the password into the config file as well. The way I would normally do it is to make a bean out of `IamPasswordCallback` and set the value in the flow and use the bean for the callback handler on the CXF setup, but I don't know what that config should look like. The alternative is to load the property file in the `IamPasswordCallback` class, but I believe that is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new wsconsumer component, you can give the user and password directly from config file.

```
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="test.wsdl" service="testService" port="test" serviceAddress="${url.endpoint}" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Config">
    <ws:security>
        <ws:wss-username-token username="${user}" password="${password}" passwordType="TEXT"/>
    </ws:security>
</ws:consumer-config>
```

If you have to stick with CXF, then you can use a spring bean definition as below:

In your global elements,

```
<spring:bean id="WSSCallback" name="WSSCallback" class="test.ClientCallback">
    <spring:property name="SoapPassword" value="${password}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

And have the below or similar code in your callback class:

```
public class ClientCallback implements CallbackHandler {
    private String SoapPassword;
    public String getSoapPassword() {
        return SoapPassword;
    }
    public void setSoapPassword(String soapPassword) {
        SoapPassword = soapPassword;
    }
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

        // set the password for our message.
        pc.setPassword(SoapPassword);
    }
}
```

Now in your cxf-client have the below config:

```
   <cxf:jaxws-client enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="SOAP" clientClass="client.class" operation="testop" port="testport" wsdlLocation="test.wsdl"> 
    <cxf:ws-security> 
        <cxf:ws-config> 
            <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken"></cxf:property>  
            <cxf:property key="user" value="${user.name}"></cxf:property>  
            <cxf:property key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"></cxf:property>  
            <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="WSSCallback"></cxf:property>  
        </cxf:ws-config>  
    </cxf:ws-security>              
</cxf:jaxws-client>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The property doesn't seem to want to be a string?
`java.lang.ClassCastException: za.co.entityapi.IamPasswordCallback cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.getString(WSHandler.java:1220)
 at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.getCallbackHandler(WSHandler.java:923)
 at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.getPasswordCallbackHandler(WSHandler.java:939)`

Comment: I using Mule 3.6.2 BTW

Comment: Oh okay.. this was working in 3.4. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Okay, I am able to get this working in Mule 3.7 with the sample code I have. If you are still looking for an answer, please post your modified flow and class so that I can take a look. Thanks.